# Can't exit 'emacs -nw' with 'C-x C-c'

Tags: emacs, gpg

I was editing .gpg file and when I was done emacs couldn't exit. When I pressed C-x the emacs said

```
"File to save in: /home/my/dir"
```

Then when hit C-c, it said

```
"Save file /home/my/dir/myfile.gpg? (y, n, !, ., q, C-r, d or C-h)"
```

Neither option exits emacs.
Neither C-x and C-c is overloaded. I suspected that it has to do with automatic encryption/decryption by emacs of .gpg files, but it doesn't make any sense in this case and is very annoying.

How do I just shut it in this case from within emacs?

Comment: What happens if you first save the unsaved file `myfile.gpg` and then exit with `C-x C-c`?

Comment: drewbenn, I'm asking how to *exit* it, not how to kill the process

Comment: Johan, sorry, I didn't describe it, but I do try to save it with C-x C-s every time. It opens the encryption prompt window and gives the same message.